# ¿Cómo establecer el tamaño de un arreglo dinámicamente?

Tags: c++, array

Necesito declarar un arreglo cuyo tamaño sea indicado por el usuario, ¿Cómo puedo realizarlo?

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código pero da error.

```
 int t;
printf("Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: %d", t);
scanf("%i", &t);
```

Comment: Por curiosidad, cuando dices "arreglo" ¿Te refieres a variable? Es la primera vez que lo leo así...

Comment: @ArnauCastellví "arreglo" se refiere a array. A los programadores hispanohablantes europeos nos suena bastante raro pero para los programadores hispanoparlantes americanos es relativamente común. Hay una [discusión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discusi%C3%B3n:Vector_(inform%C3%A1tica)#arreglo_vs_.22array.22) al respecto en la Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza un puntero a memoria para declarar tu arreglo y luego lo inicializas con la función `malloc`:

```
int n;
cout<<"Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: ";
cin>>n;
int *m = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Tal como indica @rnd, también puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
int n;
cout<<"Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: ";
cin>>n;
int *m = new int[n];
```

Comment: En c++ es preferible usar `new int[n]` pues a diferencia de`malloc`, si lanza excepciones `std::bad_alloc`. Esta practica te obliga verificar si m es nulo antes de usarla.

Answer (score 7):

Pese a que las respuestas de [Luiggi Mendoza ♦](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6636/2742), [rnd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6639/2742) y [Loreto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6682/2742) son correctas, todas ellas se basan en el uso de punteros y el operador `new`.

Sin embargo, las tendencias modernas de C++ lo encaminan a un desuso de *punteros en crudo* en favor de otras estructuras de datos como `std::vector` o punteros inteligentes; así pues, mi consejo es que uses estas estructuras de datos si quieres programar "C++ moderno".

Puedes usar [`std::vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) así:

```
std::vector<int> m; // Declaracion del vector.
int n=0;
cout<<"Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: "; cin>>n;
m.resize(n);        // Asignacion del tamanyo.
```

Podrás acceder a los datos de la misma manera que en el caso de usar punteros: con el operador `[]`:

```
m[0] = 0xFabada; // Asignar valor del primer elemento.
int x = m[1];    // Leer el valor del segundo elemento.
```

Una de las ventajas de la plantilla `std::vector` respecto a las soluciones basadas en punteros es que realiza automáticamente la gestión de memoria, en consecuencia te ahorras tanto el `new[]` como el `delete[]`, ya que la memoria dinámica solicitada en el [`std::vector::resize`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) se libera en el destructor del objeto, el cuál es llamado al salir del contexto donde se declara.

Otra ventaja es que podrás usarlo en el bucle for de rango añadido en C++11; este bucle se basa en las funciones libres [`std::begin`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) y [`std::end`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) que no están disponibles para arreglos dinámicos ya que no se puede deducir su tamaño:

```
for (const auto &x : n) std::cout << x << '\n';
```

Otra opción es usar un [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), que dispone también de la ventaja de la auto-gestión de memoria (no debes gestionar el borrado, se libera la memoria al salir de contexto) y se puede usar con el operador `[]` pero al igual que la solución con punteros, no se puede usar con el bucle for de rango:

```
int n;
cout<<"Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: "; cin>>n;
auto m = std::make_unique<int[]>(n);
m[0] = 0xcafe5010; // Asignar valor del primer elemento.
int x = m[1];      // Leer el valor del segundo elemento.
```

---

Mi consejo es que evites en la medida de lo posible usar *punteros en crudo* y utilices `std::vector` o `std::unique_pointer` pues sus ventajas son evidentes y están más acorde con las tendencias del C++ moderno.

Answer (score 4):

Utiliza el operador `new[]`, tiene la ventaja de en caso de no poder alocar memoria suficiente, lanza la exception `std::bad_alloc`. Utilizar malloc/free es una mala idea, pues si no hay memoria retorna `NULL` (o `nullptr` en c++11 y superior) y tienes que verificarlo en cada caso.

```
int* m = new int[n];
```

Recuerda luego liberar la memoria utilizando

```
delete [] m;
```

Answer (score 2):

pongo acá las variantes para crear un objeto en la memoria libre con new, que es la forma "C++" de hacerlo, aunque en C++ los arrays y punteros son la última de las opciones; mucho antes estaría std::vector, por ejemplo.

El operador new no sólo asigna memoria dinamicamente sino que invoca al constructor del objeto, lo que no puede hacerse con malloc y familia.

En el ejemplo se crean tres arrays de ints, con y sin inicialización:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout << "n = ";
    std::cin >> n;

    int* a = new int[n]; // sin inicializar 
    int* b = new int[n] {}; // inicializado con ceros
    int* c = new int[n] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // inicializado con la "initializer_list"
                                         // y ceros en lo que falte

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << " - " << b[i] << " - " << c[i] << '\n';
    }

    // y no olvidar
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La utilización de matrices con tamaño dinámico se puede lograr a través de la utilización de la memoria dinámica con punteros. Para c, la mejor forma de establecer el tamaño dinámico de memoria a través de las función malloc de la librería `<stdlib.h>`.

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es declarar un puntero a puntero, o sea **"un puntero doble `**` que es un puntero cuya variable apunta a otro puntero y este a su vez al valor final del dato."**. Por ejemplo.

```
int **m = NULL; //Puntero doble con valor inicial NULL (nulo o vacio)
```

A seguir, utilizas la función malloc para guardar memoria para las filas `fil` de la matriz:

```
m = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*fil); /* donde sizeof(int) es el tamaño
                                de la memoria para una variable de tipo entera */
```

`sizeof(int *)` es multiplicado por el número de filas dentro de la función malloc, utilizando puntero doble para ingresar a la porción de memoria designado a la matriz.

Por último creamos las columnas para cada una de las filas a través del puntero, usando:

```
for(int i=0;i<fil;i++)
    m[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
```

Y por último tenemos que liberar el espacio de memoria utilizado usando:

```
free(m);
```

Te dejo un ejemplo completo: **Crear una matriz de tipo entera preguntándole al usuario el número de filas y columnas, después llenar la matriz e imprimir.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int fil, col;
    fil=col=0;
    int **m = NULL;

    printf("Digite el número de filas: ");
    scanf("%i",&fil);

    printf("Digite el número de columnas: ");
    scanf("%i",&col);

    m = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*fil);
    for(int i=0;i<fil;i++)
        m[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*col);

    for(int i=0;i<fil;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("m[%i][%i] = ",i,j);
            scanf("%i",&m[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(int i=0;i<fil;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            //printf(" %i\t",m[i][j]); // También sirve
            printf(" %i\t",*(*(m+i)+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    free(m);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

También podrías simplemente pedir primero el tamaño y luego declarar el arreglo:

```
int n;

cout<<"Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: "; cin>>n;

int m[n];
```

Comment: Hola! gracias por la respuesta. Por favor mira [answer]. Por que esta respuesta es mejor que las otras? se mucho mas claro en lo que queres decir.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int tamFilas = 0, tamColumnas = 0, contador = 0;

    do {
        cout << "Elige un tamaño entre 1 y 10 para las filas: ";
        cin >> tamFilas;
        cout << endl;
        if(tamFilas > 0 && tamFilas < 10) break;
        cout << "El tamaño es incorrecto vuelve a intentarlo." << endl;
    } while(true);

    do {
        cout << "Elige un tamaño entre 1 y 10 para las columnas: ";
        cin >> tamColumnas;
        cout << endl;
        if(tamColumnas > 0 && tamColumnas < 10) break;
        cout << "El tamaño es incorrecto vuelve a intentarlo." << endl;
    } while(true);

    vector<vector<int>> datos;
    vector<int> fila(tamFilas);

    for(int i = 1; i <= tamColumnas; i++) {
        for(auto & ele : fila) {
        cout << "Ingrese valor " << contador + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> ele;
        cout << endl;
        contador++;
        }
        {auto it = datos.end(); datos.insert(it,(fila));}
    }
    for(int i=0; i<tamFilas; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<tamColumnas; j++){
            if (j==0) {
                cout << endl << datos[i][j] << " "; 
            }else{
                cout << datos[i][j] << " ";
            }
        }
    }

{cout << endl << endl << "En pausa...";system("pause");}

return 0;
}
```

Este es el código que use para presentar matrices dinámicas con tamaños variables. Espero que les sirva un abrazo!